# Отложенная рассылка сообщений Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii

Подскажите, не могу найти примеров. 
Необходимо реализовать отложенную рассылку сообщений. Пользователь выбирает дату и время когда он хочет что бы его рассылка началась. Например дата через 3 дня.
Эта дата записывается в поле БД. 
Как повесить событие на эту дату и время ? что бы при наступлении этой даты вызвался метод по рассылке

использую фреймвор Yii2

Comment: Четвертый результат выдачи Google - http://old.webasyst.ru/support/help/settingup-cronjob.html
Неужели так сложно воспользоваться поиском? 
https://phptime.ru/yii/otpravka-email-uvedomleniy-v-yii2.html - пятая ссылка если добавить в поиск слово yii2

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать консольную команду, которая будет проверять наличие заданий и если есть задание, то выполнять его. А команду поставить в крон.

Comment: Если задание выполнено, то помечать его соответственно, что бы не дублировать рассылку.